# Add new quicklaunch navigation link on SharePoint site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, navigation

I want to add a QuickLaunch link to a site using powershell.

The script I am currently using is:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sp_3/Deps
$node = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode 
    -ArgumentList "LinkTitle", "http://sp_3/Deps/SUP"
$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Add($node);
$web.Update()
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Can not find an overload for the "Add" and the number of arguments: "1."  line: 1 char: 32  
     + $ Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Add <<<< ($ node);
     + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ah!  [This page](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/03/managing-quick-launch-navigation-in.html) has the most excellent tutorial and example.  Here is what worked for me (SP 2010)

```
$quickLaunch = $currentWeb.navigation.quicklaunch
$libheading = $quickLaunch | where { $_.Title -eq "Libraries" }
$newnode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode($whattitle, $myurllink, $true)
$libheading.Children.AddAsLast($newnode)
$currentweb.update()
```

Comment: A warning on this when using SharePoint 2013 to create nodes that point to document libraries: Adding the node as above fails to create a **drop-enabled** link. So for that case, rather set the list.OnQuickLaunch property to get the node auto-created.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer there for the other folks.  I'm still stuck on 2010, myself. +1

Answer (score 1):

The method [`SPNavigationNodeCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnodecollection.add.aspx) needs a second parameter - an existing [`SPNavigationNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode.aspx) to place the newly added one behind it. You can find one [by URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.getnodebyurl.aspx), e.g., or by enumerating the collection. Or just place your new one to the front ([`AddAsFirst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnodecollection.addasfirst.aspx)) or to the back ([`AddAsLast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnodecollection.addaslast.aspx)).

```
$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast($node)
```

**Update:** How to add a link to the Sites group:

```
$quickLaunch = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
# Print the $quickLaunch collection and choose a property
# identifying the best the link group you want. I chose URL.
$sitesUrl = "/sites/team/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"
$sitesGroup = $quickLaunch | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $sitesUrl }
$sitesGroup.Children.AddAsLast($node)
```

--- Ferda

Comment: ok) thanks! '$web = Get-SPWeb http://sp_3/Deps
$node = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -ArgumentList "LinkTitle", "http://sp_3/Deps/SUP",1
$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Add($node);
' Use this code I get a fat link to your site.
 (Now my link is located on the Quick Launch bar apart, lonely)
 Question: How do I make my link was under titled Sites?

Comment: Sites is a link and a link group at the same time. See the update in my answer how to append a child link to it.

Comment: I get an error on the last line (...Addaslast($node)...) that `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expresssion` - I can't figure that out.

Comment: Something was `$null`. Check if `$quickLaunch` contains one item. Check if you assigned a new navigation item to `$node`.